# Children's novel about time travel via steam train

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Nothing to do with the end scene of Back To The Future Part 3! I'm trying to remember a novel I read when I was a child, so it was from the 1970s or earlier. It was in English and set in England. It was about a boy who discovered a disused platform at his local railway station, from where he got on a steam train which took him to exactly the same place but in the past. On his first trip he saw himself as a baby in a pram. Later on in the story he was able to travel back to before he was born by "lodging" in the mind of an older man.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Old Powder Line](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31624926-the-old-powder-line) by  Richard Parker

> Brian goes for a ride on a mysterious steam train that takes him back
>   into his childhood.

[From Alice to Harry Potter: Children's Fantasy in England](https://books.google.com/books?id=FDZaAAAAMAAJ):

> ...Richard Parker's The Old Powder Line (1971), a story of journeys from
>   a strange extra platform in a station, where a steam train takes
>   people to their pasts. On one trip teenage Brian meets himself as a
>   baby, and finds his mother half-recognising him.

[The School Librarian, Volumes 18-19](https://books.google.com/books?id=A1vpAAAAMAAJ), 1970:

> The time traveller cannot cross the frontier of his age and remain
>   bodily whole, a problem faced when Brian, as a thought-shape, goes
>   back to rescue Arnold from the 1920s and then returns for someone old
>   enough to go back physically. This scientifically arranged chronoclasm
>   is supplemented by astral-plane projection: the comatose body of
>   Arnold, in hospital, shows the very symptoms of Arnold-in-the-past
>   trapped in a tunnel.

Comment: That's the one! I was a member of The Puffin Club (a children's book-reading club run by Penguin Books) when this book was published, so I probably got a copy through that at the time.